# VHDL : how to write data in FIFO (first in first out) and read data with diffrent clocks for the writing and reading?

Tags: vhdl

So I have this problem . I need data to be saved in a FIFO . but the problem is that the I need different clock for the writing and the reading . for exmaple I need that MY FIFO will write the data in frequency 50 M Hz ,and after the FIFO is full to read this data but with frequency  of 960 Hz . I know that in point of hardware it is not possible because in FIFO you have the same clock for writing and reading . But is there any other way to save data in some sort of memory and then read this data from the memory in different frequency  ?

I drew simple pic of my meaning [image]

Comment: Every FPGA vendor has a library which has a so-called asynchronous FIFO. I would recommend using those as developing one yourself is difficult and error prone.

Comment: Yep, spot on @oldfart. Use vendor IP.

Comment: In Xilinx parts the dual port block rams can be used for clock domain crossing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you're thinking of the FIFO as a shift register.  It isn't; it's more efficiently implemented as a circular buffer.  Keep your data in a memory location, and use two independent pointers for read and write.  Those pointers can be updated in different processes.

As others have said, use vendor IP where applicable, especially for synthesis.  If you're looking for a behavioural model, or for some other reason can't use the vendor-supplied model, the circular buffer is the way to go.